# Give css to selected image

Tags: jquery

Whichever image I choose, I want to give image css on the other page. I can give css to a tag but not img. Can someone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        let url = window.location.href;
          $('.sku-url').each(function() {
           if (this.href === url) {
               $('.sku-img').addClass('selected');
            }
         }); 
     });
```

```css
img {
width:200px;
}
.selected{
width:250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="sku-url" href="#"> <img class="sku-img" src="https://relial.org/uploads/eventos/099dab05274e0a43a0ea385ade587d88.gif"> </a>
<a class="sku-url" href="#"> <img class="sku-img" src="https://www.viewhotels.jp/ryogoku/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2020/03/test-img.jpg"> </a>
<a class="sku-url" href="#"> <img class="sku-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/95/Test_image.jpg"> </a>
```

Comment: you can use `$(this).find('.sku-img').addClass('selected');`

Comment: Your code works, but it will set 250px to ALL images.

Comment: @cloned You said exactly what I was looking for, but I ran into a problem. When I addClass, I need to use important in my css class, otherwise it overrides the css, how can I overcome this?
I don't use important anywhere else.

Comment: By being more specific with your selectors. Read up on how [CSS specifity works here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 1):

Your code will change ALL images with that class. Instead only change the child image

I assume the # will be changed to something that might match the URL

```js
$(function() {
  let url = window.location.href;
  $('.sku-url').each(function() {
    $('.sku-img',this).toggleClass('selected',this.href === url);
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}

.selected {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="sku-url" href="#"> <img class="sku-img" src="https://relial.org/uploads/eventos/099dab05274e0a43a0ea385ade587d88.gif"> </a>
<a class="sku-url" href="#"> <img class="sku-img" src="https://www.viewhotels.jp/ryogoku/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2020/03/test-img.jpg"> </a>
<a class="sku-url" href="#"> <img class="sku-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/95/Test_image.jpg"> </a>
```

Comment: Nice idea using the toggleClass here, didn't know about that usage. +1 for it.